# assigning variables from array c#

Tags: c#

I am learning arrays in c# and have  a problem with assigning variables.

1st class:

```
public int H = 10;
public int V = 10;

//BlaBlaBla MonoBehaviour class with variables
public BlaBlaBla[,] blablabla;

void Start()
{
    blablabla = new BlaBlaBla[H,V];

    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++) 
        {
            blablabla[i, j] = new BlaBlaBla(); 
        }
    }
```

in class 2 cast on class 3 from class 1 ...Instantiated(blablabla, H, V)

3rd class

```
public BlaBlaBla[,] azaza;

public void Instantiated(BlaBlaBla[,] wakawakawaka, int HH, int VV)
{
    azaza = wakawakawaka;

    for (int i = 0; i < HH; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < VV; j++) 
        {
            GameObject sss = Instantiate(sssGameObject);
            sss.GetComponent<BlaBlaBla>() = azaza [i, j]; // ERROR:The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, a property or an indexer
        }
    }
```

If I assign variables like this, it works fine:

```
sss.GetComponent<BlaBlaBla>().text = azaza [i, j].text;
sss.GetComponent<BlaBlaBla>().someINT = azaza [i, j].someINT;
```

As I understand it, the array doesn't store an instance of the class. Only variables and so on, but what to do if there are hundreds of them. How do I assign them?

Comment: Considering you are using a custom class I fail to see how this counts as an array. Furthermore the basic notation to assign a array position value is array name[indexPosition] = value. 

From a rough guess it seems like you made a matrix, but that might jus be me.

Anyhow some more info about the basic class structure, what is not working and the operation you expect is needed to give a proper answer.

Comment: it would be helpful if you included the `class` definition around your classes, and used more descriptive names in order to make your code more readable and the intent clearer.

Comment: `GetComponent()` likely returns a component. You can't assign something directly to a method like that. The reason you can do `GetComponent().text = someText;` is because you're referencing the `text` property of the component that's returned from the `GetComponent` method. Unless there's a `SetComponent` or some other way to assign the entire component to a new object, you'll likely have to update the properties as you are.

Comment: Rufus L you're right. But this function does not exist. So I asked for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a definition of your `sssGameObject` and `GetComponent()` I can only identify the problem at a high level and not in detail. The issue is that you're trying to assign that value to the result of a method call which is invalid.

You need to identify a property to assign to, or find a corresponding `SetComponent<Blablalba>(azaza[I, j]);` to use.

Your latter calls to that set the text property work because when you do that, the compiler creates a reference that you can address and set the property for. So in short, your GameObject will need a SetObject method.

Comment: this script for game engune Unity3d. sss this is an abstract game object, which the script Blablalba. Blablalba contains many variables. sss.GetComponent<BlaBlaBla>() using this method, I can assign values, but one by one.

Comment: Include your definition of `Instantiate()` in your question and that way it will be much easier to assist.

Comment: this function is an in engine, it creates an instance of the game object. [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)